# List fron nested object using list.js

Tags: listjs

I am trying to make a list from data from a geojson file used in open layer.
my data looks like

`var json_2 = [ {"properties": { "zona": "Italia", "nome": "A"} }, {"properties": { "zona": "Italia", "nome": "I" } } ]`

I am not able to do it, also if I tried in many way. I not sure it is possible.
To be clear I **don't** need to do a nested list. I just want to have something like

- Italia - A
- Italia - I

It is possible without parse the data?

tried with dot notation and bracket notation too. No way. I prepared a file to do the test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

  <script src="./list.js"></script>
  
  <div id="lista">

  <ul class="list">
  </ul>

</div>

<script> var json_naz_2 = [
{"properties": { "zona": "Italia", "nome": "A"} },
{"properties": { "zona": "Italia", "nome": "I" } }
]
 </script>
 <script>
console.log(json_naz_2); 
console.log(json_naz_2[0]); 
console.log(json_naz_2[0].properties);
console.log(json_naz_2[0].properties.zona);
console.log(json_naz_2[0]["properties"]);
console.log(json_naz_2[0]["properties"]["zona"]);
</script>
 <script >var options = {
valueNames: [ 'zona', 'nome' ],
item: '<li><h3 class="zona"></h3><p class="nome"></p></li>'
  }; </script>

  <script> var userList = new List('lista', options, json_naz_2); </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

changed valueNames and item in many way. no lucky

thanks to who can help

Comment: (I see a -1 - I try to guess why somebody may have downvoted) Thanks for this question. Note that this is not "parsing". This is adapting data. Generally, adapting data on-the-fly may be good, especially if your your original data structure is not a standard one and/or will probably not fit the library's expected input.

Comment: I then noticed over the years that StackOverflow is more focused on creating useful questions also for other people, as opposed to very vertical questions about specific issues on specific custom formats that are not frequent to other people "zona", "nome", etc. - so if you want to avoid some downvotes, eventually evaluate a question deletion (I deleted I think 40 questions in my life - that perfectly OK sometime). Thanks and sorry if Stack Overflow is sometime boring :)

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for? Parse the values and populate list.

```
  const mylist = [];
  for (variable in json_naz_2) {
    mystr =
      json_naz_2[variable].properties.zona +
      " - " +
      json_naz_2[variable].properties.nome;
    mylist[variable] = mystr;
    console.log(mystr);
  }
  console.log(mylist, typeof mylist);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./list.js"></script>

    <div id="lista">
      <ul class="list"></ul>
    </div>

    <script>
      var json_naz_2 = [
        { properties: { zona: "Italia", nome: "A" } },
        { properties: { zona: "Italia", nome: "I" } },
      ];
    </script>
    <script>
      const mylist = [];
      for (variable in json_naz_2) {
        mystr =
          json_naz_2[variable].properties.zona +
          " - " +
          json_naz_2[variable].properties.nome;
        mylist[variable] = mystr;
        console.log(mystr);
      }
      console.log(mylist, typeof mylist);
    </script>
    <script>
      var options = {
        valueNames: ["zona", "nome"],
        item: '<li><h3 class="zona"></h3><p class="nome"></p></li>',
      };
    </script>

    <script>
      var userList = new List("lista", options, json_naz_2);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: --> Is this what you are looking for? Parse the values and populate list. <br> First thank for your reply. <br> Your suggestion is a good solution, but my question was to do it referring directly the data without parse. I take note of your code anyway, because if I will not arrive to do it in another way I will do something like that.